# Get how many files a user choose using JFileChooser

Tags: java, file

In my program I am using a JFileChooser. The user can select multiple files using the JFileChooser. If the user selects only one file, only a **File** object is returned, and is retrieveable using `fileChooser.getSelectedFile()`. If the user selects more than one file, a **File[]** is returned, and is retrievable using `fileChooser.getSelectedFiles()`.

At the moment I am using a try/catch block to grab whatever type is returned using said methods. I feel as if this is a bad way of doing it.

Is there any way to check what type of object will be returned (e.g whether I should receive an Array)? I can't seem to find a method in the API to do so.

Comment: whatever the problem (don't quite understand your description - but think @woliveirajr has the answer :-) a try/catch block is not a solution

Answer (score 4):

If you allow user to select more than one file, them you should call the `get.SelectedFiles()` and receive an array as answer.

Since it's an array, you can see the numbers of components to see how many files were selected (one, two...) and them interact through it to do anything you want.

And if you discover that it received just one file, act like you want.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make sure only certain types of files can be selected you should set a file filter

```
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter()
    {
      public boolean accept(File file)
      {
        return file.isDirectory() ||
               file.getName().endsWith(".abc");
      }
      public String getDescription()
      {
        return "Your files *.abc files";
      }
    });
```

Comment: he also mentions types of files returned, that why I thought my post maybe helpful